# Sharing variables between WorkFlow Application / SIngelton Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

i am running a c# application that is launching workflow activities for some purposes (using invokeworkflowapplication). I would like to be able to share a static class between all flows i am launching from my application (some sort of singelton class that they can all acccess at any time).

Is there such a method to make the flow i am launching run in some singelton context??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice way to share data between different workflows and instances is to make a workflowInstanceExtension. This extension must be added by your application and its same instance be used to all your WorkflowApplications, invoker or service, so it will be a "singleton".

Example:

```
MyDataSharingExtension dse = new MyDataSharingExtension();

WorkflowApplication wfApp1 = new WorkflowApplication();
wfApp1.Extensions.Add(dse);

WorkflowApplication wfApp2 = new WorkflowApplication();
wfApp2.Extensions.Add(dse);
```

Then, inside an activity, you can call

```
context.GetExtension<MyDataSharingExtension>().GetData();
```

If you need the data at workflow level(not code), you could make a custom activity to retrieve the data to a variable.

If it don't fit your needs, take a look at this implementation of [enterprise variables](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112285/Enterprise-Variables-for-WF4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any VB expression you want inside your workflows so you can just access a singleton object. You can also add the same object to each WorkflowApplication using the Extensions collection. In that case you can use retrieve the object inside of custom activities but not using VB expressions.